# Insert data from xml to database during the server start, in spring framework

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, entity

I have some entities, and a lot of data in xml that I have to parse and insert to database after the entities will be created.

My question is what is the best practice to do it?

Can I parse each xml inside of each entity and how?

Comment: And what should happen if you redeploy the application/restart the server?